# Best way to initialise fields in a Class without boilerplate code

Tags: java, initialization, lombok

I have a `PivotModel` class which I will initialise using the `new` keyword.

```
PivotModel pivotModel = new PivotModel()
```

When `pivotModel` gets initialised, all the dependant fields(model1, model2,cell1,cell2) should get initialised with new object but not to null.
I wanted to initialise all the fields and the fields of dependant classes without using new constructor. I don't want to have boilerplate code.

If you have any standard practice of way doing it, post it here. I am also using `lombok` in my project.

```
public class PivotModel {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Model1 model1;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Model2 model2;

    private Model3 model3 = new Model3() -----> Dont want to initialise this way for these fields 
}

public class Model1 {
    private Map<String,Cell> cell1;
    private Map<String,Cell> cell2;
    private Map<String,Cell> cell3;
    ------ will have some 10 fields here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are using Lombok project in your java project you can add `@Getter @Setter` above your class Scope, Lombok also provides Constructor Annotation, so Just type above your class Scope `@AllArgsConstructor`
so you class Should be like this

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PivotModel {
    private Model1 model1;
    private Model2 model2;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Model1 {
    private Map<String,Cell> cell1;
    private Map<String,Cell> cell2;
    private Map<String,Cell> cell3;
}
```

Comment: I am using Lombok in my project.When i initialise PivotModel class , I want all the fields in this class initialised with new object.For all the dependent classes also i want all the fields to get initialised.

Comment: Yes All fields, Constructor will do this job because @AllArgsContructor 
provide you to set all parameter as mandatory parameters

Comment: @Basil: **Lombok** provides `@NoArgsConstructor`.

Comment: @MontassarElBéhi maybe i got a mistake i just took a very fast overview about it, thanks for correcting me

Comment: It's pretty cool. Using [`@Data`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) makes you really fast! You're welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

For initialization, I would recommended **Builder Pattern**.

```
//keep your initialization logic in builder class and use build()/create() wherever required. Let's say:
Class Pivot{
 // Note: this have only getters for members

 //inner builder class
 PivotModelBuilder{

   //Note: all setter will be part of builder class

   /**
     * method which return instantiated required object.
    */
   public PivotModel build(){
        return new PivotModel(this);
    }
  }
}
//access initilization code as:
PivotModel pivot = new Pivot.PivotModelBuilder().build()
```

Adding referral link: https://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html
(*You can search more about builder pattern and it's implementation online*)

Limitations:

- However, it's good way to initialize/create bean, but, you might find duplication of member fields in both Parent and builder class.